# Передача сообщения через указанный промежуток времени Handler

Tags: java, android

Всем привет! Столкнулся вот с таким вопросом:

У меня в `MainActivity` имеется вложенный класс, который наследует класс `Thread`, похожее что-то на такое:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  public onCreate(Bundle bundle) {}

  private class MyThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
      while(condition) {

      } 
    }
  }

}
```

Мне необходимо из потока `MyThread` каждые две секунды отправлять сообщение в элемент `View`, не загружая задержками поток `MyThread`. Поток `MyThread` должен всегда выполняться без задержек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Time is :" + OffsetDateTime.now());
       // todo
    }
}
```

и вызов

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TimerTask task = new ScheduledTask();

        Timer time = new Timer();
        time.schedule(task, 0, 2000);
    }
}
```